# When the edit text is clicked how to set a value in edit screen of edittext then user can change it

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have got an edit text. It's value is set to 90.00 programatically. When I click the edittext to edit it must show 0.00 in the edit screen and then user can edit it to may be 50.00. How to achieve this in Android

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULWWg.jpg

I tried something like this but edit text gets changed when I close the edit screen of edit text.

```
textPayNote.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                        textPayNote.setText("0.00");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: do it with setOnTouchListener.ACTION_DOWN

Comment: @EliasFazel It worked Thanks bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `OnTouchListener` on your EditText & set/append text on `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`.

Comment: textPayNote.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                textPayNote.setText("0.00");
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

Answer (score 2):

```
textPayNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textPayNote.setText("0.00");
        }
    });
```

OR

```
textPayNote.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (focused) {
                textPayNote.setText("0.00");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: With the first snippet, it works on the second instance. I click the edit text it takes to edit screen no changes. When I click the edit text again, the value is zero on edit screen.

Comment: With second snippet, On first click, it gets changed to 0.00 but it doesn't take me to the edit screen . I have click once again to go to edit screen. Is there any way we can do this one click

Comment: Add this to your EditText in the layout.xml file and it should work as expected. android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

Comment: <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/idPayNoteText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:text="Amount"
                    android:textColor="@color/bootstrap_brand_secondary_text"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>                              It didn't work

Comment: textPayNote.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                        if (textPayNote.isFocused()) {
                            textPayNote.setText("0.00");
                        }
                    }
                });

Comment: These are two code snippets from .xml and .java files. I have added for your reference. When I clicked it nothing happened. Even the edit screen didn't appear

Answer (score 1):

As Elias Fazel pointed out setOnTouchListener did the trick.

```
textPayNote.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                textPayNote.setText("0.00");
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Thanks @EliasFazel

Comment: I wrote the answer please rate and accept it as the answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/payNote"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:hint="Amount"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


textPayNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textPayNote.setText("0");
        }
    });
```